# MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value with PHP

Tags: regex, mongodb

i wan't search article_id LIKE '34%'

I use:

> $cursor = $collection->find(array('article_id' => new
>   MongoRegex("/^34/")));

But, return FALSE

Help me

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB's regex only works on strings. So if you need this capability but also want the ability to do Number like queries such as $gt, then you need to duplicate your field and have it stored once as a Number and once as a String.